# Change button background image in swift

Tags: swift

I am programming a dice app.
I know how to change the image to different dice faces if I use UIImage view. But I want to use a UIButton for dice so that every time a user presses the dice button with a particular dice face image, the image updates to another dice image. I know how to use the arc4random to randomly change the image but I don't know how to apply that same concept on a UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func myImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button-Normal"), for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

Comment: I know this already. I want to use UIButton instead of UIImage and then change the button background programmatically.

Comment: @ndarji Wait, what? Why are you setting the background whether than the button image itself using `yourButtonName.setImage()`?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: awesome the above code:  "@IBAction func myImageButton" worked. The only change I had to do is use sender.setBackgroundImage instead of sender.setImage. thanks to Meagar or Kevin Morris whosoever suggested this to me. very much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @KevinMorris OP needs to have at least 15 reputation to gain upvote privilige.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 4, the answer should be:

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Button-Normal"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5

```
btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_btn.png"), for: .normal)
```